# get content in HTML where name= 'XXX ' using python

Tags: python

I use python 2.7 in Windows 7.

I have a HTML file and I want to get the content where name='XXX'

My code:

```
import bs4
exampleFile = open('test.html')
exampleSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(exampleFile.read(), 'html5lib')
for item in  exampleSoup.find(name="XXX"):
print item.get_text()
```

My HTML file:

```
<h1><a name="XXX"></a>StubStr</h1>
<table width="100%" border="1" bordercolor="black" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr align=center valign=top>
<td width="20%" style='width:20%' align=left>Number (psid)</th>
<td width="20%" style='width:20%' align=left>0x0002</th>
<td width="60%" style='width:60%' align=left>2</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>Type</td><td colspan=2>octet_string</td></tr><tr><td>Default</td><td colspan=2>None</td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr>
<th colspan=3 align=left valign=top>Allowed Values</th>
</tr>
 <tr><td>Minimum string length</td><td colspan=2>0 octets</td></tr><tr><td>Maximum string length</td> 
 <td colspan=2>128 octets</td></tr><tr><td colspan=3 align=left valign=top><p><b>Dummy string MIB 
entry
 </b></p><p>A MIB string entry that can be harmlessly read or written, e.g.,
  for testing.
```

I want to get these text: A MIB string entry that can be harmlessly read or written, e.g.,
for testing.

But I failed to get the that using my code :TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: The element `<a name="XXX"></a>` has no text content

Comment: So how could I get these text:  A MIB string entry that can be harmlessly read or written, e.g., for testing.

Comment: do you simply want to get the last p tag of the html? if so you can just use `exampleSoup.findAll('p')[-1].text`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you jsut want to get the text from the last `<p>` tag then you can use the findall method to locate all `<p>` tags and then access the last index on the list. The bellow is written in python 3 but can easily be adapted to python 2

```
my_html = """<h1><a name="XXX"></a>StubStr</h1>
<table width="100%" border="1" bordercolor="black" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr align=center valign=top>
<td width="20%" style='width:20%' align=left>Number (psid)</th>
<td width="20%" style='width:20%' align=left>0x0002</th>
<td width="60%" style='width:60%' align=left>2</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>Type</td><td colspan=2>octet_string</td></tr><tr><td>Default</td><td colspan=2>None</td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr>
<th colspan=3 align=left valign=top>Allowed Values</th>
</tr>
 <tr><td>Minimum string length</td><td colspan=2>0 octets</td></tr><tr><td>Maximum string length</td> 
 <td colspan=2>128 octets</td></tr><tr><td colspan=3 align=left valign=top><p><b>Dummy string MIB 
entry
 </b></p><p>A MIB string entry that can be harmlessly read or written, e.g., for testing."""

import bs4
exampleSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(my_html, features="lxml")
print(exampleSoup.findAll('p')[-1].text)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
A MIB string entry that can be harmlessly read or written, e.g., for testing.
```